# Django get object info to method without re-entering it

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm not exactly sure how to explain it. I am trying to use "custom save method" sort of. At any rate, hopefully my code makes sense.

I am currently testing a `CustomUser` `model`. I want to generate a `username` if none is given. I am also using the `full_clean` method as to not save instances that are blank. Here's what I have:

test

```
# Don't get hung up on the way I create the user. I have a reason for this.
user = {
    'username': '',
    'password': 'testpassword',
    'first_name': 'Testy',
    'middle_name': 'Tester',
    'last_name': 'Testman',
    'email': 'testman@test.com',
}

def test_CustomUser_will_generate_username_if_none_provided(self):
    CustomUser(**user).full_clean_save()
```

model method:

```
def full_clean_save(self):
    # How do I get my 'username' reckognized here if it isn't ''?
    # This always is == ''
    if self.username == '':
        # Makes a random username from BaseUserManager
        self.username = CustomUser.objects.make_random_password()

    self.full_clean()
    self.save()
```

## Second Edit:

Found that this test broke my other tests. This actually does work. I have also been informed to use `create_user` for security reasons.

## Edit:

However the problem is that every time this method is run, it generates a username, even if one is given:

test:

```
user = {
    'username': 'Test_User',
    'password': 'testpassword',
    'first_name': 'Testy',
    'middle_name': 'Tester',
    'last_name': 'Testman',
    'email': 'testman@test.com',
}

def test_CustomUser_will_save_user(self):
    c = CustomUser(**user).full_clean_save()

    self.assertTrue(CU.objects.filter(**user).exists())

# asserts False because c.username == 'FFQ4CUK8GWnf' instead of Test_User
```

The `if` statement is not the issue, because this gives the same result:

```
def full_clean_save(self):
    if self.username == '':
        self.username = CustomUser.objects.make_random_password()
        self.full_clean()
        self.save()
    else:
        self.full_clean()
        self.save()
```

Comment: umm use else after if

Comment: sorry what's the exact problem? You get an error? What's not working?

Comment: I updated my question @VaibhavVishal

Comment: I updated my question @dirkgroten

Comment: Do you really need a new method `full_clean_save` why don't you override the `clean_fields` method of model.

Comment: Is your `CustomUser` model a subclass of a Django `AbstractUser`?

Comment: it is `AbstractBaseUser`. I will check the `clean_fields` override. I want `first_name` and `last_name` to be required, so I didn't think I could use `AbstractUser`. And I think I found that one of my other tests was breaking the rest of them. I was `@skip`ing them and then it worked.

Comment: You should never create a user this way, because as your method is now, you're saving plain-text raw passwords in the database. Use the `create_user` method instead, which will hash the password and save it correctly to the database.

Comment: Anyway there's no reason why `self.username == ''` from the code you show, So please show how you define the `CustomUser` model (especially if you override the `__init__` method)

Comment: I don't override the `__init__` method. I am trying to test that when a user(in my specific case, a customer) creates their account, the can make a username. If they don't, I want it to generate one for them. It looks like I need to look into hashing.

Comment: Check the [tag:__dict__] attribute of the object while creating, to see the scope of variables and values that are to the point of contact with the object. Print self.__dict__ to see values that are binded.